# filtring data of a csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a [CSV file](https://quera.ir/college/assignments/13609/download_problem_initial_project/60406/) which has stock market data by date and symbol. It has various columns like date, Max price, Min price and so on. I must resample these data with 10 days frequency from last four months of 2019 until the first three months of 2020, and then filter the `Min.mean()` above than 20000 and `Max.mean()` less than 35000. i wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
stock_df = pd.read_csv('stock_data.csv')
stock_df.drop(columns = ['Unnamed: 0'],inplace=True)
column_names = {
"تاریخ":"str_date",
"اولین قیمت":"Open",
"نماد":"Symbol",
"نام":"Name",
"قیمت پایانی":"Close",
"قیمت آخرین معامله":"Last Trade",
"تعداد معاملات":"Quantity",
"حجم":"Volume",
"ارزش":"Value",
"کمترین قیمت":"Min",
"بیشترین قیمت":"Max",
"قیمت دیروز":"Yesterday Price",
"تغییر":"Change"}
stock_df.rename(columns=column_names,inplace=True)
stock_df["date"]  =  pd.to_datetime(stock_df["str_date"])
```

The original attempt was like this:

```
stock_df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
result = stock_df.loc["2019-09":"2020-03"].resample('10D').Max.mean()<=35000 & stock_df.loc["2019-09":"2020-03"].resample('10D').Min.mean()>=20000
```

`stock_df` is the DataFrame that holds CSV file data. The final answer must put in the dataframe `result`. but this code gets this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sets and sorts your index on date, then selects your date range.

Because you have multiple symbols the `groupby` needs to be explicit about the resample on `date`. It then takes the mean of the two columns you mentioned.

Finally, it creates the boolean conditions you asked for, cuts the `tmp` dataframe to select only those rows, resets the index to make it "flat" again, and puts a copy of the result into `result`.

```
tmp = stock_df.set_index(['date', 'Symbol']).sort_values(['date'])
tmp = tmp.loc[pd.IndexSlice['2019-09-01':'2020-03-31', :], :]

tmp = tmp.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='date', freq='10D'), pd.Grouper(level='Symbol')])[['Max','Min']].mean()

cond1 = (tmp.Max <= 35000)
cond2 = (tmp.Min >= 20000)
result = tmp[cond1 & cond2].reset_index().copy()
```

You should verify that the results are what you expect, perhaps on a smaller dataset where you know the result ahead of time. Hopefully that gives you enough to work with.

Comment: I added the CSV file and wrote the full code. i tried your code but when running command:   `res = np.load("answers.npz")
assert res["values"].shape == (12,2)
assert str(res["index"][0]) == '2019-09-03T00:00:00.000000000'`
i face this error : `Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False`

Comment: I edited the answer (and the question) to address your update. The last line you should keep from the original question is `stock_df["date"]  =  pd.to_datetime(stock_df["str_date"])` before trying this.